# How to place labels in a ms word template and fill them with data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, ms-word

I need to make an application where users upload a certain document template (Word, etc.) and they place in it controls (labels, textboxs) with certain ids and based on the ids of the controls, I have to fill the template with data from SQL server and then make the word document filled with data available to download.

Is it anyway I can do with using C# and APS.NET, Javascript, Jquery, etc.?

I don't really know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The template will also be uploaded by the user.

Comment: i know but i am asking is there any standard of the template, like how many fields will be already written on template.

Comment: it's like a form where you have to write down your name and other personal data. the user will upload the document and place the label "NAME" in the blank box where you're supposed to write your name, and then the app will generate X number of word documents with different names that are on a certain table of my database

Comment: retrieving data from SQl, editing document template and make document available for download are 3 different tasks.

Comment: You can use Mail merge  and book marks.

Comment: @WajidAli I have no problem with the first and the last task. edit the template doc is my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched a little bit and I found out that the solution to my problem is [**Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124)

I never used it and I guess I have to search a lot until i can use it in my application. Hopefully, It will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

You can make you document from template as like below:

```
priavte void CreateWordDocument(string InputFileNamePath, string OutputFileNamePath)
    {

    Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();   

    doc = app.Documents.Open(InputFileNamePath,ref missing, ref missing,ref Missing, ref Missing);
    // Activate document
    doc.Actiavte();
    //Find place holders in input template and replace them with database values

    this.FindAndReplace(app,"<Name>","John"); //take all values from database 
    this.FindAndReplace(app,"<Address>","Test address");
    this.FindAndReplace(app,"<City>","Test City");

    //Save file
    doc.SaveAs(ref OutputFileNamePath, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

    doc.Close(ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,)
    }
```

Visit link for more help : http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/howdoi/how-do-i-modify-word-documents-using-c/190

Comment: The application needs to be more dynamic. I will have to get the data from the database and the user has to find its corresponding place in the document. In another situation for example, there will be: Name: _________________ and i'll have to put the name in the blank place...

Answer (score 1):

When you code it yourself in C#, please also take care of the following aspects:

1. Headers and footers deserve separate handling when working on the document directly. When you have multiple the same values on a page of a repeating element, I have found it easier to always put the first defined value in the header and the last defined value in the footer when they have a reference.
2. Try not to use the XML representation; headers and footers are a lot harder to process in the XML document when replacing the original XML.
3. Tables can cause problems; when you use the text representation of the document to parse the content (and which is required when you want to insert repeating rows) tables introduce an offset between the text presentation and the cursor position in the document. You will need to add extra anchors inside the table manually or use the XML representation.
4. Or use TAB-s instead of tables in your document when you need a table like structure.
5. When you need to repeat pictures or frames or other more advanced features, they are easier than tables. If you have only a limited list of pictures to be used such as a signature of the CxO-s, put them all in the Word document and remove the ones not needed at all or not needed to be repeated.

For uploading, I recommend remembering to set metadata properties (which makes life easier for document management systems) and using a webservice or alike to get it processed on the backend.